# How to pass the value of a variable from one component to another in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I use two components:
-"*CartContainer.jsx*" to count the cost of products that user has added to the cart.

**UPDATED:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useStateValue } from "../context/StateProvider";
import { actionType } from "../context/reducer";
//another imports
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import PaymentContainer from "./PaymentContainer";

const CartContainer = () => {
    const [{ cartShow, cartItems, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
    const [flag, setFlag] = useState(1);
    const [tot, setTot] = useState(0);

    //another methods

    useEffect(() => {
        let totalPrice = cartItems.reduce(function (accumulator, item) {
            return accumulator + item.qty * item.price;
        }, 0);
        setTot(totalPrice);
        console.log(tot);
    }, [tot, flag]);

    //another methods

    return (
        <motion.div initial... animate... exit... class...">

        //something code

            {/* bottom section */}

        //something code

                    {/* cart total section code */}
                    <div class...>
                        <div class...>
                            <p class...>Sub Total</p>
                            <p class...>$ {tot}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class...>
                            <p class...>Delivery</p>
                            <p class...>$ 2.5</p>
                        </div>

                        //another code

                        <div class...>
                            <p class...>Total</p>
                            <p class...>${tot + 2.5}</p>
                        </div>

                        {user ? (
                            <Link to={'/payment'}> *//it's link to PaymentContainer*
                                <motion.button whileTap={{ scale: 0.8 }} type="button" class...>Check Out</motion.button>
                            </Link>
                        ) : (
                            //another code
                        )}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <PaymentContainer totalAmount={tot} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            ) : (
        //another code
            )}
        </motion.div>
    );
};

export default CartContainer;
```

-"*PaymentContainer.jsx*" this component works with Stripe.js and has a "**amount**"-variable.

**UPDATED:**

```
import React from "react";

const PaymentContainer = ({totalAmount}) => {
  const containerAmount = totalAmount;
  console.log(totalAmount);
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Total: {containerAmount}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PaymentContainer;
```

I want the total cost of items from "CartContainer.jsx" to be assigned to the "**amount**"-variable in "PaymentContainer.jsx"
Thank you all :)

I found a similar question in this forum and tried to apply the solution, but I couldn't.
I tried to adapt this code in file "PaymentContainer.jsx"

```
  const handleInputChange = (e) => {   
  const valueFilterActive = document.getElementById("activeFilter").value;
  const valueFilterName = document.getElementById("bussFilter").value;
  // this will set `inputValues` variable to be an object with `valueFilterActive` and `valueFilterName` properties
  setInputValues({valueFilterActive, valueFilterName})
  alert(valueFilterName+valueFilterActive);   
};
```

**UPDATED:** App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import { CreateContainer, Header, MainContainer, PaymentContainer } from "./components";
import { useStateValue } from "./context/StateProvider";
import { getAllFoodItems } from "./utils/firebaseFunctions";
import { actionType } from "./context/reducer";


const App = () => {
    const [{foodItems}, dispatch] = useStateValue();

    const fetchData = async () => {
        await getAllFoodItems().then(data => {
            dispatch({
                type : actionType.SET_FOOD_ITEMS,
                foodItems : data,
            });
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <AnimatePresence mode="wait">
            <div class...>
                <Header />

                <main class...>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/*" element={<MainContainer />} />
                        <Route path="/createItem" element={<CreateContainer />} />

            //here PaymentContainer
                        <Route path="/payment" element={<PaymentContainer />} /> here PaymentContainer
            //here PaymentContainer

                    </Routes>
                </main>
            </div>
        </AnimatePresence>
    );
}

export default App
```

### **UPDATED:**

### Browser console when I add products to cart and get the amount but when I go to "Payment Container" by "Link" the value is undefined.

[image: BrowserConsole]

Comment: It looks like the code is already doing what you ask for with `<PaymentContainer totalAmount={tot} />`. What exactly is the issue? Also, don't console log as an unintentional side-effect, use the `useEffect` hook to log state and props updates.

Comment: The problem is that the data is apparently passed to "PaymentContainer", but nothing is displayed. So, it only shows "Total: " - without Amount.

Comment: You mention a link. What exactly are you linking to? Are you rendering another `PaymentContainer` component somewhere that ***isn't*** passed any `totalAmount` prop?

Comment: <Link to={'/payment'}> *//it's link to PaymentContainer from CartContainer*, I used '/payment' in App.js and render it there, I add code of "App.js" to post

Answer (score 3):

in React, you can pass data to other components via props or global state, so one way would be to render the `PaymentContainer.jsx` inside the `CartContainer.jsx` and pass data to it.

For example:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
// your other imports
import PaymentContainer from "./PaymentContainer";

const CartContainer = () => {
    const [tot, setTot] = useState(0);
    // your previous data

return (
  // your previous stuff
  <PaymentContainer totalAmount={tot} />
 )
}

export default CartContainer
```

Your payment Container would also need to receive the props to view

```
const PaymentContainer = ({totalAmount}) => {
  console.log(totalAmount)
  // your previous stuff
  return (
    // your previous stuff
  )
}
```

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: Sorry for bothering you. When I add items to the cart, the browser console shows that the data is being sent to "PaymentContainer" but when I go to "PaymentContainer" the value is "Undefined".       // I add picture to question) Thank you very much)

Comment: update the question with the 2 components ("PaymentContainer" and "PaymentContainer") being connected to each other

Comment: So, I just deleted the other post and added the code UPDATE and result picture here.

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

You are rendering the `PaymentContainer` component in *at least* two places, once in `CartContainer` where a `totalAmount` prop is passed:

```
<div>
  <PaymentContainer totalAmount={tot} />
</div>
```

And once in the routes where no props are passed:

```
<Route path="/payment" element={<PaymentContainer />} />
```

It is the second that when navigated to by the `Link` in `CartContainer` that the total is undefined.

## A Solution

It's not clear why you are rendering `PaymentContainer` in two places *differently*, so I'll ignore this part. If you want to render `PaymentContainer` on a route and pass data to it you will pass it in route state via the link.

The `tot` state is actually also unnecessary since it's *derived* "state" from the *actual* `cartItems` state. It's generally considered a React anti-pattern to store derived state in React state. You should compute and use it locally per render cycle.

Note that in almost 100% of the use cases where you find yourself coding a `useState/useEffect` hook combo what you really should use is the `useMemo` hook to compute ***and memoize*** a stable value reference.

Examples:

```js
const totalPrice = cartItems.reduce(function (accumulator, item) {
  return accumulator + item.qty * item.price;
}, 0);
```

```js
const totalPrice = React.useMemo(() => {
  return cartItems.reduce(function (accumulator, item) {
    return accumulator + item.qty * item.price;
  }, 0);
}, [cartItems]);
```

Code Example:

```
const CartContainer = () => {
  const [{ cartShow, cartItems, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(1);

  // another methods

  const totalAmount = React.useMemo(() => {
    return cartItems.reduce(function (accumulator, item) {
      return accumulator + item.qty * item.price;
    }, 0);
  }, [cartItems]);

  // another methods

  return (
    <motion.div initial... animate... exit... class...">
      ...

      {user ? (
        <Link to="/payment" state={{ totalAmount }}> // <-- pass totalAmount in state
          <motion.button
            whileTap={{ scale: 0.8 }}
            type="button"
            class...
          >
            Check Out
          </motion.button>
        </Link>
      ) : (
        //another code
      )}

      ...
      <PaymentContainer totalAmount={totalAmount} />
      ...
    </motion.div>
  );
};
```

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const PaymentContainer = ({ totalAmount }) => {
  const { state } = useLocation();

  const containerAmount = state.totalAmount || totalAmount || 0;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(totalAmount);
  }, [totalAmount]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Total: {containerAmount}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};
```